# Google Apps Script Disable copy and paste

Tags: google-apps-script

How to disable copy and paste inside Google spreadsheet?
i have spreadsheet enable user to insert and update data inside spreadsheet 
i make request to my server on onedit event to each cell and i'd like to prevent user from make copy and paste because on edit event return false data on copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

You cant disable it.
Even if you do you will have More errors because onEdit doesnt handle other things like inserting rows and others.
You need to use onChange to detect the other events.